# Access Provider variable in child widget methods

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to access `branchSelected`, a Provider declared towards the top of my code in the scaffold's child widgets. When I use branchSelected.branchDropdownValue in the original widget, it works. However, when I go into the child widget methods, specifically

```
ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: () {
          branchSelected.branchChange;
          /*
          refreshBranchData();
          refreshProjectData();
          */
        },
        child: Icon(Icons.refresh))
```

, I received the error "Undefined name 'branchSelected'." Looking at other documentation, I thought that all child widgets should be able to access the Provider; however, that doesn't seem to be the case here. Any ideas? I've attached my code below:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
final branchSelected = Provider.of<branchListChanges>(context);
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text('Build Launcher'),
  ),
  body: Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
    child: Column(
      children: [
        _buildTopRow(),
        Consumer<branchListChanges>(builder: (context, data, child) {
          return Text(
              'Current Branch: ${branchSelected.branchDropdownValue}');
        }),
        _buildList(),
      ],
    ),
  ),
  backgroundColor: Colors.grey[200],
);
}

Expanded _buildList() {
// Sets which branch to view for the list runs

return Expanded(
  child: RunList(branches, "main"),
);
}

Row _buildTopRow() {
return Row(
  children: [
    Text("Project:"),
    SizedBox(width: 6),
    ProjectDropdown(packages),
    SizedBox(width: 6),
    Text("Branch:"),
    SizedBox(width: 6),
    BranchDropdown(branchNames),
    SizedBox(width: 6),
    Checkbox(
      checkColor: Colors.white,
      fillColor: MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(Colors.blue),
      value: onlyLatestPerDay,
      onChanged: (bool? value) {
        setState(() {
          onlyLatestPerDay = value!;
        });
      },
    ),
    SizedBox(width: 3),
    Text("Only latest per-day"),
    SizedBox(width: 6),
    Checkbox(
      checkColor: Colors.white,
      fillColor: MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(Colors.blue),
      value: onlyInstalled,
      onChanged: (bool? value) {
        setState(() {
          onlyInstalled = value!;
        });
      },
    ),
    SizedBox(width: 3),
    Text("Only installed"),
    SizedBox(width: 6),
    ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: () {
          branchSelected.branchChange;
          /*
          refreshBranchData();
          refreshProjectData();
          */
        },
        child: Icon(Icons.refresh))
  ],
);
}
}
```

I created my Provider in `main.dart` attached below:

```
class HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return MaterialApp(
    title: 'cornerCan',
    theme: ThemeData(
      primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
  ),
  // EFFECTS: runs mainPage function in main_page.dart
  home: ChangeNotifierProvider<branchListChanges>(
    create: (context) => branchListChanges(),
    child: mainPage(),
  ),
);
}
}
```

Comment: Can you show your main.dart ? It's possible that you have not yet created the Provider

Comment: I added my main.dart code where I created my provider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The scope of your branchSelected variable is only inside the build function. You need to declare it outside the build function to access it.
2. You can also pass it as a parameter to the _buildTopRow() function
   e.g. _buildTopRow(branchSelected)